# Does any command available to Import bacpac file from Azure Blob to Azure SQL Database

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have created SQL Azure under Resource Group using AzureResourceManager mode.

I am trying to Import bacpac file from Azure Blob to Azure SQL using `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport` command but it's look like this command is not available with AzureResourceManager mode. (it's available with AzureServiceManagement mode.)

Does any similar command available with AzureResourceManager mode?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is not an Azure Resource Manager command for Azure SQL Database's Import functionality. For a list of currently supported Azure Resource Manager commands for Azure SQL Database [please look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt574084.aspx).

Comment: Link is broken as of 2018 08 04

Answer (score 0):

As of AzureRm PowerShell 5.7.0, there are dedicated cmdlets for importing and exporting bacpacs directly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/AzureRM.Sql/New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport?view=azurermps-5.7.0

Caveat: you have to store the .bacpacs in an Azure Storage Account.